# Perl hash not initialising as expected

Tags: perl

I am getting unexpected results from a Perl hash (associative array).

I am trying to populate it from a CGI post, where some form values might be missing.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

my %data = (
        'key1' => $cgi->param('fkey1'),
        'key2' => $cgi->param('fkey2'),
        'key3' => $cgi->param('fkey3'),
        'key4' => $cgi->param('fkey4'),
        'key5' => $cgi->param('fkey5'),
        'key6' => $cgi->param('fkey6'),
        'key7' => $cgi->param('fkey7'),
        'key8' => $cgi->param('fkey8'),
        'key9' => $cgi->param('fkey9'),
        'key0' => $cgi->param('fkey0'),
    );

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n<pre>";
print Dumper \%data;

my $fkey1 = $cgi->param('fkey1');
my $fkey2 = $cgi->param('fkey2');
my $fkey3 = $cgi->param('fkey3');
my $fkey4 = $cgi->param('fkey4');
my $fkey5 = $cgi->param('fkey5');
my $fkey6 = $cgi->param('fkey6');
my $fkey7 = $cgi->param('fkey7');
my $fkey8 = $cgi->param('fkey8');
my $fkey9 = $cgi->param('fkey9');
my $fkey0 = $cgi->param('fkey0');


my %data2 = (
        'key1' => $fkey1,
        'key2' => $fkey2,
        'key3' => $fkey3,
        'key4' => $fkey4,
        'key5' => $fkey5,
        'key6' => $fkey6,
        'key7' => $fkey7,
        'key8' => $fkey8,
        'key9' => $fkey9,
        'key0' => $fkey0,
    );

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n<pre>";
print Dumper \%data2;
```

%data is completely wrong. I have to do it like %data2. The output of this is:

```
$VAR1 = {
     'key9' => 'key0',
     'key5' => 'key6',
     'key1' => 'key2',
     'key7' => 'key8',
     'key3' => 'key4'
   };

$VAR1 = {
    'key9' => undef,
    'key5' => undef,
    'key6' => undef,
    'key8' => undef,
    'key0' => undef,
    'key3' => undef,
    'key2' => undef,
    'key1' => undef,
    'key4' => undef,
    'key7' => undef
  };
```

So if $cgi->param('fkey1') is undef, it skips the value and uses the next key as the value. Is there something I need to do to get %data working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is due to the way that `param` behaves in list context vs. scalar context.

In scalar context, if a parameter doesn't exist, `param` returns `undef`. In list context, it returns an empty list. So suppose you have a hash initialization like this:

```
my %data = ( foo => $cgi->param( 'foo' ),
             bar => $cgi->param( 'bar' ),
             baz => $cgi->param( 'baz' ) );
```

And suppose that the parameter `bar` does not exist. Since `param` is called in list context, the list passed to the hash initialization ends up looking like this:

```
( 'foo', 'foovalue', 'bar', 'baz', 'bazvalue' )
```

Note that there's nothing after the `bar` key, because an empty list was returned there.

To fix it, you can force all calls to `param` into scalar context:

```
my %data = ( foo => scalar $cgi->param( 'foo' ),
             bar => scalar $cgi->param( 'bar' ),
             baz => scalar $cgi->param( 'baz' ) );
```

Now the list will look like this:

```
( 'foo', 'foovalue', 'bar', undef, 'baz', 'bazvalue' )
```

And everything is right with the world again.

Answer (score 4):

CGI.pm already provides a way to [fetch the parameter list as a hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FETCHING-THE-PARAMETER-LIST-AS-A-HASH%3a) using the `Vars` method:

```
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
my %params = $q->Vars;
```

Multi-valued parameters are returned as a packed string separated by the null character `\0`. You have to split the string to get the individual values.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to provide a default for empty values, as that will force `param` to return in a scalar context.  It also has the dual benefit of fixing use of uninitialized value warnings:

```
my %data = (
    'key1' => $cgi->param('fkey1') // '',
    'key2' => $cgi->param('fkey2') // '',
    'key3' => $cgi->param('fkey3') // '',
    'key4' => $cgi->param('fkey4') // '',
    'key5' => $cgi->param('fkey5') // '',
    'key6' => $cgi->param('fkey6') // '',
    'key7' => $cgi->param('fkey7') // '',
    'key8' => $cgi->param('fkey8') // '',
    'key9' => $cgi->param('fkey9') // '',
    'key0' => $cgi->param('fkey0') // '',
);
```

However, if this code is anything more than an example, it could be simplified to just:

```
my %data = map {"key$_" => $cgi->param("fkey$_") // ''} (0..9);
```

Btw, if you'd like to test when a function like param would be called in an array context, you could use the following code:

```
sub test {
    if (wantarray) {
        print "<array>\n"; return ();
    } else {
        print "<scalar> - $_[0]\n"; 
        return undef;
    }
}

my %h = (
    key1 => test('array'),
    key2 => scalar test('scalar'),
    key3 => test('logical defined-or') // '',
    key4 => test('logical or') || '',
    key5 => test('concat') . '',
);
```

Output shows that any of the above methods can force a scalar context.  I'd only use `scalar` or `//` though:

```
<array>
<scalar> - scalar
<scalar> - logical defined-or
<scalar> - logical or
<scalar> - concat
```